# PROMPT_COMMAND for other historied commands (mysql, psql, etc.)

Tags: bash, mysql

I have

```bash
export PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a; history -c; history -r'
```

in my `.bashrc` and would be lost without it. I usually have 3+ windows and 20+ `tmux` panes at all times, and this means that I get history saved immediately and then available in the other panes, also immediately (after an <kbd>Enter</kbd> anyway). It means that even without `tmux`, I get my history saved, for example when a connection drops (reboot, whatever) and I lose a session.

Is there any way of getting this in a generic way with other historied commands? I'm thinking mainly about `psql` and `mysql` but I'm open to anything that allows me to get history flushed after every command.

Comment: Your shell does not even see inputs read by programs,  so it cannot log them. There's no generic way, unless you want to wrap `psql` and `mysql` in `expect` (see `man expect`), but that's  difficult.

Comment: You might want to look into `rlwrap`, but I don't think that will give you that immediately shared history.

Comment: I, too, have a strong desire for this. psql already integrates readline and saves its history to file at the end of each session, but there's no way I can find to save that history more frequently (beyond manually running the `\s` meta command).